# Saving loaded objects without the relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, unit-of-work

Hi is it possible to save the loaded object with relationship to save without the relationship?

Example, i have loaded this object:

```
ICollection<User> users = objectContext.Users.Include("Things").Where(n => n.UserId == "0");
```

Then add new item to the collection:

```
users.Add(new User { UserId = "1", Name = "Juan dela Cruz" });
```

And save the collection to the database, update if existing and add if it's not, is it possible to save the objects without including the "Things" which is also loaded using eager loading?

Comment: Can't you leave out the include?

Comment: No since i'm using the included relationship to display data, I already got a work around, I just iterate thru the collection and set the "Things" property as null before saving. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since in example shown by above you are not modifying you don't need to load "Things"

```
ICollection<User> users = objectContext.Users.Where(n => n.UserId == "0");
```

Comment: hi, I didn't include it but i'm using the "Things" to show data that's why I use eager loading.

Comment: If you dont wanted to save "Things" just set its entity state to Unchanged.